# before delete trigger 3

Tags: apex

i am trying to create a trigger on custom object in which i am preventing the user to delete the record where `Email id= sample@gmail.com` and i have tried this.

```
 trigger EmailTrigger on Candidate__c (before delete) {

    for(Candidate__c can:trigger.old){
    if(can.Email__c=='sample@gmail.com'){
    can.addError('error');
    }
    }

}
```

i just want to know is this the right way to do it. can anybody suggest me the right code if i am worng.

Comment: the only thing i can suggest is don't hardcode the Id. if you want to change in future then you have to do lots of thing.

Comment: hi tushar,
actually i am new in sales force and i am trying my hands on triggers that's why i'hv hardcoded it.

Comment: use Custom setting to store email id and then retrieve them in your class. Also best practices says to use handler class for this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Before Delete Triggers primarily operate on trigger.old. See the Apex [Code Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm) for more on this. What you want to do is remove records from trigger.old that meet your criteria so they don't get deleted when the DML operation occurs.

Your code adjustments would look like:

```
for(Candidate__c can:trigger.old){
    if(can.Email__c=='sample@gmail.com'){
        can.isDeleted = false;
    }
}
```

I believe the above should prevent the record from being deleted.

Comment: `trigger.new` is not available in before delete trigger.

Comment: Read the docs. It is indeed available. It just can't be manipulated. if you want to do an update, it has to be done to trigger.old.

Comment: as per docs `Not allowed. A runtime error is thrown. trigger.new is not available in before delete triggers.`

Comment: Check your answer again. I have shared a image. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I stand corrected. my eyes are tired and I was looking at the wrong line. I went to grab a screen capture and saw the line you've posted. The important thing is that he needs to remove the Id then from trigger. old. Wil edit that part of the post. Thank you for catching my error.

Comment: Happy to help. :)